# Add list item to dict

Tags: ansible

I need to create a dictionary of lists dynamically but I don't understand how to add list items to dictionary elements using `set_fact` with Ansible.

```yaml
    # Defining the dict

    - name: Fist dict element
      set_fact:
        messages_array: "{{ messages_array | default({}) | combine({'foo': [] }) }}" 

    - name: Second dict element
      set_fact:
        messages_array: "{{ messages_array | default({}) | combine({'bar': [] }) }}"
```

Now I would like to add a list on each dict element.
The output should be like the following one.

```yaml
messages_array:
  foo:
    - foo_one
    - foo_two
    - foo_three
  bar:
    - bar_one
    - bar_two
    - bar_three
```

Is there a way to add list items using `set_fact` and `with_items` loops?

Comment: What prevents you to write the data directly as the one you give as an expected result? This looks like an [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info): where are you getting that data from and how does it look like originally?

Comment: From [Ansible Best Practices: The Essentials](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials) "_Think declaratively: Ansible is a Desired State Engine by design. If you’re trying to “write code” in your plays and roles, you’re setting yourself up for failure. Our YAML-based playbooks were never meant to be for programming._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with folks in the comments; if you find yourself trying to *manipulate* data in a playbook, you're generally doing the wrong thing. In many cases, moving your logic into Python code as a custom filter or module is a much better choice.

That said, you **could** do something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    messages_array: {}
  tasks:
    - name: First dict element
      set_fact:
        messages_array: "{{ messages_array | combine({'foo': [] }) }}"

    - name: Second dict element
      set_fact:
        messages_array: "{{ messages_array | combine({'bar': [] }) }}"

    - name: Add items to messages_array.foo
      set_fact:
        messages_array: "{{ messages_array | combine({'foo': messages_array.foo + [item]}) }}"
      loop:
        - foo_one
        - foo_two
        - foo_three

    - name: Add items to messages_array.bar
      set_fact:
        messages_array: "{{ messages_array | combine({'bar': messages_array.bar + [item]}) }}"
      loop:
        - bar_one
        - bar_two
        - bar_three

    - debug:
        var: messages_array
```

This produces as output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "messages_array": {
        "bar": [
            "bar_one",
            "bar_two",
            "bar_three"
        ],
        "foo": [
            "foo_one",
            "foo_two",
            "foo_three"
        ]
    }
}
```

I've kept your variable naming, but note that `messages_array` isn't an array; it's a dictionary.